# Convert String[] to String need CRLF without using \n\r

Tags: c#, regex, string, printing

We’ve been using Michael Mayer’s Report Printing:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4934/Printing-Reports-in-NET
Yeah, it’s old!

So my problem… We have a Text Box that has Carriage Return and Line Feeds, ex:

```
THIS
IS

A
TEST
```

Producing a file to print freezes. I have traced this down to the \r\n in string, ex:

```
"Mailing Address:  123 Main Street, Wherever, MD  12345\r\n\r\nFacility 1:\r\nProperty Address:”
```

I know how to do things like split it into a String[] and I can use Regex and Replace and get rid of the \r\n. BUT, ultimately, I want to reconstitute it and have the CRLF, but I can’t use \r\n or Environment.NewLine.

Any thoughts about how I can use this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing \r\n with just \n?

Comment: So, are you saying you want to preserve that the CRLF is there, but "encode" it and "decode" it later?

Comment: You're confusing me... "have the CRLF, but I can't use \r\n or Environment.NewLine"... `\r\n` **is** CRLF; it is exactly the same thing; synonymous. Can you clarify your intent here? (note: `Environment.NewLine` is more subtle, as it may depend on where you are executing, i.e. Mono on linux etc)

Comment: I have tried with just \n and it did not work. Yes, I get it's confusing. Is there another way to get CRLF without using \n\r?

Comment: James - I think that's what I'm saying. I want to try the below GetEncoding(1250).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something like this with a project of mine. You can use a function called Replace to replace the characters like this:

```
myStringWithCRLF.Replace("CRLF", "<---------------New Page-------------->");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about the solution, since I never dealt with printing, but maybe it has something to do with encoding?

```
System.IO.StreamWriter ansiWriter = new StreamWriter("file.txt", false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
```

This helped me to avoid issues with new lines when I am saving the file.